# Custome Exception message are not sent by Google Endpoint API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have Created the API . I want to show the custom Error message when  user is entering  wrong id , leave id blank  or enter any value which is not present in the system.  For the example purpose i am throwing Exception when user is entering the id not equal 1 but api is not returning the custom Error Message.

Please help me  to find what i am doing wrong? I appreciate every help and suggestion.

```
 @Api(name = "subUsers", version = "v1")
 public class UserEP {
   @ApiMethod(name = "getException", path="getErrorException/{id}",   httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
      public SubscriberUserImpl getErrorException(@Named("id") int id) throws NotFoundException{
       SubscriberUserImpl subscriberUser = null;
       if(id!=1){
          **throw new NotFoundException(" user ID  is Not Found : " +id);**
        }
        else {
           return subscriberUser; 
        }
  }
```

}

after deploying it on local i tried  id  value

1. "iuwyriwuy"
2. 4
3. ""
4. white space

   I got endpoint generated Exception message not custom Exception. The complete idea of this question is  how to get custom message when api user is inserting something  wrong. How  to handle the exception.

   API  : GET https://1-dot-gcpapp-140012.appspot.com/_ah/api/subscribeUsers/v1/getErrorException/{id}

Comment: Can you paste the full response message you get?

Comment: @saiyr  i  getting standard error message like 404 ,204

Comment: @saiyr  i  getting standard error message like 404( for blank input ) ,204(int value), 400(string input). My api is GET https://1-dot-gcpapp-140012.appspot.com/_ah/api/subscribeUsers/v1/getErrorException/{id}